# Normal discontinuity at seam of dash moulding?

Tags: honda, fit, dash

I've brought my 2013 Fit LX to Honda for many things.  Flood remediation, entailing replacement of all electronic components and harnesses at floor level.  Airbag recalls on both the driver and passenger sides.  Replacement of the hand brake cable after the flood remediation.

I'm not sure, but I suspect tht some of the above entails removal and re-assembly of the front dash.

Lately, I have found that a discontinuity in the dash surface at a seam is causing discomfort on my knee.  Here is a picture:

[image]

Is the seam normal?

I'm tired of imposing on Honda to fix things.  The last time was the hand brake cable, which was a real challenge.  Lots and lots of time lost there.

If the seam is not normal, I might just roll over and have them charge me for it.  I'm not sure yet.

How reasonable is it to insist that they resolve the discontinuity -- if it is not supposed to be there, that is?

Comment: Remember, the Fit is an entry level car. It won't have the fit/finish (no pun intended) of an Acura. My suggestion is ... don't rest your leg there. I've got long legs, so have to ensure I'm not leaning them up against the sides, which can cause pain in the side of my knee. Anway, if the piece won't push back up into place, I don't think I'd be overly worried about it ... you can adjust yourself rather than adjusting the car. JMHO, so take it for what it's worth.

Comment: I think your advice is good for normal folk, but I'm abnormal in that, due to back oddities, I have to sit up close.  It feels better for long and short drives.  i find the leg room to be extremely confining, laterally and upward.  That surface in particular is confining.

Comment: I used to have smaller cars (fiat panda, Sedici aka Suzuki SX4) as they fitted the budget... But my size (and the size of my kids - tall not wide:). ) meant I had to check out many car options and I chose something with more legroom and comfort.. You makes your choice...

Comment: Indeed.  It's hard to know what discomforts are just because one isn't used to the car versus something fundamental.  I didn't have a whole lot of time to fully explore various options.  My old car needed to be retired, and I was relying on the Honda name, and the reputation of the Fit online.  The seam didn't seem so bad with long winter pants cushioning it, but with shorts, it literally bites.

Comment: Also, I'm noticing now that the seam only is a problem during long drives, in which I use cruise control.  I pull my leg back to keep my feet off the pedal, and that's when my knee is aligned with the seam.  Sign....ah well...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't expect an uncomfortable seam there, but it's certainly a possibility. My guess is a slight mismatch in the two halves of the plastic mold.  If the vehicle is still under original owner warranty take it back.  1) that provides feedback to the manufacturing folks that they can certainly make improvements. 2) it fixes the issue for you. Do note, when plastic parts are molded, the plastic is injected at a pretty high pressure.  It's possible to get a sharp edge at the die parting line. Normally I'd expect the manufacturing folks to keep a watch for this die wear from creating a problem, but mistakes are possible.

If we're talking simple discomfort, it's totally okay to CAREFULLY file / sand down the offending sharp edge.  My guess it thats injection molded ABS plastic, with the part molded in color.  (There is a risk that it's a black plastic part, then painted gray, but I doubt it.  Why is that a risk? Why you'd see black in the hand filed area, not the pretty-and-consistent-with-the-rest-of-the-interior gray)  Do note, when plastic is molded there is a strong skin formed in the part.  When you file it, or sand it you will lose some strength to the part, because you are removing the strong skin/surface.  In this case I doubt it makes a difference; that part appears to be totally cosmetic in that area.

An other alternative it to add a piece of sticky back adhesive / high density foam tape or sticky back adhesive felt (velvet) tape to preclude the sharp edge from rubbing you leg.

[image: half round file]
If it were it my car, I'd first mark the sharp area with a piece of masking tape, then I'd remove the part from the vehicle; do the work CAREFULLY on the workbench, using a [half round file](https://amzn.to/2VDR05t) to just remove the sharp edge of the part. I'd only take off a millimeter or two, no more than that. You just want to knock down the sharp edge.

Comment: Thanks, sipzit.  I live in a highrise with an underground parking spot.  No working on cars is allowed down there.  As a result, I've lost any semblance of handiness that I use to have decades ago.  I did consider how one might cushion the seam, but it sometimes gets very hot in the car.  I will ask at our local home hardware about suitable adhesive.  The drawback is that it further confines an already confining surface.  But only a tiny bit.

Answer (score 1):

I don't own one, but I've rented them.  Yes, that seam can be a bit annoying but it's also 100% normal.  I have noticed that some particular vehicles seem to have a slightly better fit there than others, but your picture seems to me to show a seam that is well within tolerance for that model, so I think we can rule out incorrect reassembly from a previous repair.

As was mentioned in a comment, while it's a perfectly good vehicle, it's also not a top-of-the line model, so not everything lines up as neatly and precisely as one might want.  I would doubt that there's much that your local dealer could do whether they were charging you for the labor or not.

Comment: I am saddened, but appreciate the info.  I may ask them anyway, to see if there is anything they can do.  At whatever the cost of labour (and parts, though I doubt any are needed).

Comment: Just out of curiosity, isn't embedded systems mostly about DSP rather than transistors?  As well, I thought bipolars were overtaken by MOS for all but extreme applications.  No need to answer if it's too private, but these thoughts were prompted by your icon.

Comment: Embedded systems engineers need a [wide range of skills](https://www.edn.com/electronics-blogs/embedded-basics/4442081/7-essential-skills-for-firmware-engineers).  As for BJT vs FET, the BJT has much better linearity for analog signal amplification.  Both still have their uses.

Comment: Interesting.  Many issues are common with technical analysis in general.  Thanks.